# Windows CMD create dynamically named directory

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, mkdir

I'm trying to create a directory in windows using CMD but the directory names need to be dynamic.

I have a batch script (.bat file) that runs database dumps into a given folder everyday, for instance `C:\Users\name\Documents\dump-destination` which then contains a bunch of `.sql` files. Now I need to `move` all those files into a directory that corresponds to the day's dump date, for instance `db-31-12-2020`

How can I dynamically create the `db-31-12-2020` directory mentioned above (with the day's date) so I can use it below?

`move C:\Users\name\Documents\dump-destination\* D:\new-dump-destination\?`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I get current date/time on the Windows command line in a suitable format for usage in a file/folder name?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/203090/how-do-i-get-current-date-time-on-the-windows-command-line-in-a-suitable-format)

Comment: For a host of other Similarly themed questions, Search: [batch-file] "date"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this code:

```
@Echo off
:: Save the day, month and year in variables
For /F "Tokens=2,3,4 Delims= \" %%a in ('Date /T') Do Set day=%%a & Set month=%%b & Set year=%%c
:: Create directory
MkDir "D:\new-dump-destination\db-%day%-%month%-%year%"
:: Move files
move "C:\Users\name\Documents\dump-destination\*" "D:\new-dump-destination\db-%day%-%month%-%year%\"
```

Comment: I'm getting `%%a was unexpected at this time` on the second statement

Comment: Edited my answer no works without any flaw

Comment: @WasifHasan: you are implementing some unwanted spaces. Switch to preferred `set` syntax: `... Do Set "day=%%a" & Set "month=%%b" & Set "year=%%c"` to avoid them. Also `tokens` and `delims` have to be adapted to the localization (for me it would have to be `tokens=1-3 delims=.")

Comment: Your answer, although edited, will probably still exhibit an error, _(`/" was unexpected at this time.`)_, so is likely to still have a flaw. You have also assumed that the OP's `Date /T` output is already in `d\M\y` order, _which is most unlikely_.

Comment: But the OP Did not face any error(Also me), @Compo.

Comment: Wasif Hasan, if I change the **`\ `** delimiter to **`/`** and tokens **`2,3,4`**, to **`1,2,3`**, (as necessary for my usual locale), my experience is that I would always receive the error message, I provided previously; _(using your code without change it would be **`\" was unexpected at this time.`**)_. Please also action the other flaw highlighted by @Stephan, which was introduced by your attempted edit to fix the issue originally indicated by the OP. BTW, the OP has not provided any indication that they didn't face a problem, _I assume they fixed it themselves, as it is a very easy fix_.

Answer (score 1):

This assumes your local date format is dd/mm/yyyy. If it is mm/dd/yyyy, you'll have to swap bits round.

```
set destdir=db-%date:~0,2%-%date:~3,2%-%date:~6,4%
md D:\new-dump-destination\%destdir%
move C:\Users\name\Documents\dump-destination\* D:\new-dump-destination\%destdir%\
```

You could use the db-%date:~0,2%-%date:~3,2%-%date:~6,4% string twice instead of using the destdir variable, but if you ran it close to midnight and the clock rolls over between the two calls, it breaks.